# Qt: Cause a layout correction without calling show()

Tags: c++, qt, layout

I'm fixing bugs in some Qt/C++ code. There's a widget that when shown the first time it's layout is wrong, but after being hidden and shown again it's layout is correct. I've scattered some tracing in the code to print the size and position of the widget's elements at various times and I can see that it's the first call to `show()` that causes the layout to correct itself. What I want to do is trigger the layout correction before showing the widget. I have tried every shot-in-the-dark I can think of. I have called `updateGeometry()`, `adjustSize()`, `layout()->update()`, `layout()->invalidate()`, `layout()->activate()`. I have called these on the widget and it's parent widget. Nothing's worked. The only thing that works is calling `show()`.

So, is there a way to cause a Qt widget to correct it's layout *without* showing it?

**Edit[0]:** I can't easily show a screenshot because it's displaying on an embedded system which is not running X. But basically; the widget consists of several labels, they start off with some default values of width and height that causes them all to be smooshed to one side of the widget. I could manually set the positions and sizes to the values I want but I know that I shouldn't need to because Qt corrects the layout perfectly after showing the widget the first time.

**Edit[1]:** Also the code that creates the layouts and labels is being autogenerated by Qt's `uic` from a Qt Designer `.ui` file.

Comment: Can you describe what precisely is wrong with the layout, maybe append a screenshot?

Comment: Does the error persist if you call `resize()` to the expected size of the widget before `show()`?

Comment: Nope, that didn't work :(. Thanks though.

Comment: Any chance of posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)? Just a small simple program that replicates the issue.